# Ecto migration: remove reference, keep field

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

In a previous migration, I defined:

```
create table(:my_table) do
  add :reference_id, references(:references), null: false
  (...)
end
```

Now I want to remove the reference and the `null: false`, but still keep the `reference_id` field.

So I want something like:

```
alter table(:my_table) do
  modify :reference_id, <SOME_TYPE>, null: true
end
```

My DB is Postgres, so I think  should be :bigint.

I have two questions:
- Is the above correct?
- If I understand correctly, this migration cannot be rolled back directly, so I have to create `up` and `down` functions. If that code is in the `up` of my migration, what should go in the `down`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bigint` looks correct to me. `id` fields in PostgreSQL are defined to be of type `bigint` by Ecto by default.

`modify` takes the same arguments as `add`, so your up code would be:

```
modify :reference_id, :bigint, null: true
```

and down would be:

```
modify :reference_id, references(:references), null: false
```

edit:

with foreign key constraints, the down will not work unless you remove the foreign key constraint in the `up` like this:

`drop constraint(:my_table, "my_table_reference_id_fkey")`